# jQuery strange hoisting/initializing behaviour

Tags: jquery, behavior

```
$(function () {
        //hard coded for initial debugging usage, must add table to reference
        var userPermissionLevelRequired = 31;
        var currentUserDescription = $('.user-menu .hidden-xs').html(); //to get user description
        var userList = null;
        var table = null;
        var userName = $.grep(userDetail, function (item) {
            return item.Description === currentUserDescription;
        });

        getUserMembers();

        /*$.ajax({

            'url': '/Home/GetUserMembers',
            'type': 'GET',
            dataType: "json",
            'success': function (data) {
                userList = data;
                populateDropDown(data);
                debugger;
            },
            'error': function (request, error) {
                alert("Request: " + JSON.stringify(request));
            }
        });*/

        function setPermission() {
            //do something...
        }
        function getUserMembers() {
            $.ajax({

                'url': '/Home/GetUserMembers',
                'type': 'GET',
                'dataType': 'json',
                'async':'false',
                'success': function (data) {
                    userList = data;
                    populateDropDown(data);
                    debugger;
                    //alert("data.length " + data.length);
                    setPermission();
                },
                'error': function (request, error) {
                    alert("Request: " + JSON.stringify(request));
                }
            });
        }
```

I wanted to add further code after the ajax call which is commented out.  But the code would run further before returning from the ajax call.  The only way I can get setPermission to run after the ajax call was to put the call in the ajax success function.  Why did I have to do this????

Comment: because `javascript` is `asynchronous`

Comment: @Bhavik Patel - Really is it that simple.  Is there any other way to handle this situation.  Please put up an answer so I can accept it please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually the $.ajax function is asynchronous by default not the javascript by itself. Using async attribute, you can actually change the behaviour to be synchronous.

However, you have to mention the `false` *without the quotes*, like below:

```
$.ajax({

    'url': '/Home/GetUserMembers',
    'type': 'GET',
    'dataType': 'json',
    'async': false,
    'success': function (data) {
        userList = data;
        populateDropDown(data);
        debugger;
        //alert("data.length " + data.length);
        setPermission();
    },
    'error': function (request, error) {
        alert("Request: " + JSON.stringify(request));
    }
});
```

in that case, the $.ajax would behave as synchronous call and you can have any statements following that and you need not call `setPersmission()` inside the success block.